# What is the term for a novel that has no chapters or paragraphs?

Tags: terminology

What is the literary term for a novel that does not have any dividing sections such as chapters or paragraphs? There may still be punctuation. I am thinking of something like Will Self's *Phone*.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange! I hope someone will be able to answer your question. However, literary critics don't have a term for every literary phenomenon. Or, as [Ronald Langacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Langacker) said, "I can think of a unicorn with daisies growing out of its nostrils, but I don't need a name for it." ;-)

Comment: I do remember hearing someone use a term for this. I just can't remember what it was :) I suspect also there will be one out there somewhere as it's a fairly well-established style.

Comment: I don't know the term, but Becket's *Malloy* is comprised of just two chapters and the first of those is a **single paragraph of 76 pages** (1,518 lines). The term that comes to mind is "unreadable". Having said that, it's a genuinely great novel!

Comment: Are you actually looking for a term for a novel or for a narrative technique?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Will Self's *Phone*, it seems the answer is "stream of consciousness", or ["stream-of-fractured-consciousness"](https://www.the-tls.co.uk/articles/will-self-consciousness/) as the linked review calls it, instead of whatever term would describe the books asked about in [Examples for books that don't use (traditional) chapters?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/976/examples-for-books-that-dont-use-traditional-chapters)

it seems no one's made a specific literary term for the lack of chapters, otherwise I'd expect people talking about the *Discworld* series to use it. So, "stream of consciousness" is likely the best we're gonna get for talking about ''Phone''.

Comment: Stream of consciousness covers much more than that, though, because it can be used with chapters

Comment: @Mary - Yeah, but it seems no one's made a specific literary term for the lack of chapters, otherwise I'd expect people talking about Discworld to use it?

Comment: And Discworld, come to that, is clearly not stream of consciousness.

Comment: @Mary - Yeah, but all we have to go on is Questioner mentioning about "Phone". Good thing there was a review for "Phone" that talked about its style. ... And if any review has found a term to talk about Discworld's lack of chapters, I'm not seeing it. ... I guess this answer is sort of a Frame Challenge? ... EDIT: Just noticed "Lack of Paragraphs", makes me think of "Wall of text".